# Help me to understand notation about orthogonal transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

Let $V$ be an euclidian space and let $T$ be an orthogonal transformation on $V$. Then we can find an orthonormal basis of $V$ with respect to which the matrix of $T$ is of the form
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
I_p & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0\\
0 & -I_q & 0 & \dots  & 0\\
0 & 0 & R_{\theta_1} & \dots  & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots  &\ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\dots & R_{\theta_k}  
\end{pmatrix},\end{equation}
where $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_k$ are real numbers and

$$R_\theta=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}.$$

What does it mean $I_p$ and $I_q$?, are they identity matrices?, I just want a better understanding of this theorem :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here $I_p$ and $I_q$ refer to identity matrices.  Presumably $p$ and $q$ are meant to indicate their size, so $I_p$ would mean there is a $p\times p$ block of $A$ which forms an identity matrix, for some $p\in\mathbb{N}$.